# Native JS equivalent to jQuery delegation

Tags: javascript, dom, dom-events, event-delegation

What is the native implementation for event delegation on dynamically created dom elements?

I tried looking at the jQuery source but I can't follow the `.on` method.

Note: Currently I attach the event handlers after the dom elements are created, which seems pretty standard but I like the way jQuery `.on` handles dynamically created elements events with this syntax `$( document ).on( "click", ".selector", handler );`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1687296/what-is-dom-event-delegation

Comment: Not a useful post already viewed that. It has outdated link references and no clear examples of what I'm trying to figure out. I know what event delegation is I want to know an example of how to do it natively

Comment: On the contrary, the question is still relevant. The highest rated answer does give you an example. Could you clarify your question then? From the question I thought you wanted to know about event delegation using plain old JavaScript.

Comment: Sorry I shouldn't say unuseful..it was useful. I was looking for more of a direct translation of the .on jquery method ( delegation protion ) to native if that exists in a "simple" form.

Comment: @GregBurghardt: It's not a duplicate, because it doesn't ask for a native implementation, but it's a good introduction to understand what event delegation is about.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Modify \`target\` of mouseEvent object for Event Delegation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28997983/modify-target-of-mouseevent-object-for-event-delegation)

Answer (score 30, accepted):

What happens is basically this:

```
// $(document).on("click", <selector>, handler)
document.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
    for (var target=e.target; target && target!=this; target=target.parentNode) {
    // loop parent nodes from the target to the delegation node
        if (target.matches(<selector>)) {
            handler.call(target, e);
            break;
        }
    }
}, false);
```

However, `e.currentTarget` is `document` when the `handler` is called, and `e.stop[Immediate]Propagation()` will work differently. jQuery abstracts over that (including call order) a lot.

I've used the [`.matches()` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element.matches), which is not yet standard but already available under different names in modern browsers. You might use a custom predicate to test elements instead of a selector. And `addEventListener` is obviously not oldIE-compatible.

Comment: So lets say I had a list (ul) and items (li) which are being added dynamically. I'd add an event listener to the ul using this approach and subsequent lis that were generated would run the handler?

Comment: Yes, because it's not the `<li>` that runs the `handler` but the listener that you've attached to the `<ul>` - to which any event in the list bubbles.

Answer (score 4):

This should do it for you on a regular HTML element:

```
HTMLElement.prototype.on = function(event, selector, handler) {
    this.addEventListener(event, function(e) {
        let target = e.target;
        if (typeof(selector) === 'string') {
            while (!target.matches(selector) && target !== this) {
                target = target.parentElement;
            }

            if (target.matches(selector))
                handler.call(target, e);
        } else {
                selector.call(this, e);
        }
    });
};
```

Comment: Do not change the prototype #smooshgate is a proof that it never ends well.

Comment: @Machado Smooshgate is proof that you can change prototypes and if you're popular the rest of the world has to conform forever. It's 2018 and MooTools still controls JS function names. Seriously though: change prototypes in your own code, just be aware if what will happen in `on` get standardized later,

Answer (score 4):

Event delegation can be achieved even without iterating through all ancestors of event target.

```
$(document).on("click", selector, handler);
```

can be written in NativeJS as:

```
document.addEventListener("click", event => {
  var el = document.querySelector(selector);
  if (el && el.contains(event.target)) {
    handler.call(el, event);
  }
});
```

Comment: This doesn't work if `selector` should return more than one node e.g. is a class selector.

Comment: @StephenBlair You are right. In that case, you may use `document.querySelectorAll(selector).forEach`.

Answer (score 1):

Felt like doing some code golfing ;)

108 bytes (based on **@Bergi**)

```
(e,d,g,h,b)=>e.addEventListener(d,c=>{for(d=e,b=c.target;b!=d;)b.matches(g)?h.call(d=b,c,b):b=b.parentNode})
```

Working demo:

```js
window.$on = (e,d,g,h,b)=>e.addEventListener(d,c=>{for(d=e,b=c.target;b!=d;)b.matches(g)?h.call(d=b,c,b):b=b.parentNode})

$on(document.body, 'click', '.clickable', (evt, matched) => {
  console.log(matched)
})
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="not-clickable rect">
    not clickable
  </div>
  <div class="clickable rect">
    clickable
  </div>
  <div class="clickable rect">
    clickable
    <div class="child">child element</div>
  </div>
</div>

<style>
.rect {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: red;
  border: 1px solid;
  margin: 10px;
  float: left;
}

.child {
  background: gray;
}
</style>
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of this JQuery

```
$(document).on('click', '.your-selector', function() {
    // do something
});
```

I use this often in pure javascript

```
document.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    // e.target can be a sub element of the one we want
    const el = e.target ? e.target.closest('.your-selector') : null;
    if (el) {
        // do something
    }
});
```

Tip: "closest" in javascript includes the element itself in the first place, and then starts to go up in the DOM

Answer (score 0):

Pure javascript code;

```
document.addEventListener("click", function (event) {
  if (event.target.classList.contains("yourClass1")) {
    //do something
  }
  if (event.target.classList.contains("yourclass2")) {
    //do something
  }
  if (event.target.id == "yourId") {
     //do something
  }
});
```

Answer (score -1):

For example, we have such an html structure.

```
<ul>
    <li>
        item 1
        <button class="btn-edit"><i class="fas fa-pencil"></i></button>
    </li>
    <li>
        item 3
        <button class="btn-edit"><i class="fas fa-pencil"></i></button>
    </li>
    <li>
        item 3
        <button class="btn-edit"><i class="fas fa-pencil"></i></button>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Note that there is an i tag inside the button.

If you want to capture exactly the right item for the Click event, you need a function like the one below.

```
function delegateClick(selector, callback){

    let selectorItems = document.querySelectorAll(selector);

    document.addEventListener('click', function(e){

        let clickedItems = e.path;

        for(let clickedItem of clickedItems){
            for(let selectorItem of selectorItems){
                if(clickedItem === selectorItem){

                    callback(clickedItem);

                }
            }
        }

    });
}
```

**This offers a very similar use to jquery.**

```
delegateClick('.btn-edit', (elm) => {

    //access the clicked DOM element
    elm;       

});
```