# cloned button node does not have click events

Tags: javascript, angular, onclick, event-handling

I am trying to clone the button, while I am able to clone the button, but for some reason the cloned button does not have the click function.

**app.component.html**:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <input type="button" (click)="CloneButton($event)" value="Clone">
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6" #cloned></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**app.component.ts**:

```
@ViewChild('cloned') cloned:ElementRef;
cloneCounter = 0;

CloneButton(event:any) {
    let newbutton = event.target.cloneNode();
    newbutton.value += this.cloneCounter++;
    this.cloned.nativeElement.appendChild(newbutton);
}
```

---

Even when I attach the javascript event listener in `CloneButton()`, it would then be unable to access the `cloneCounter` variable

```
newbutton.addEventListener('click', this.jsclicked,false)

jsclicked() {
    console.log('jsclicked');
    console.log(this.cloneCounter); //will be undefined.
}
```

**How do I clone the button, so that it still have the working click function?**

Comment: You could use a delegated event listener so it is bound automatically to any cloned items: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25248286/native-js-equivalent-to-jquery-delegation

Comment: if i use addEventListener, the delegated function is unable to access the component variables e.g., `cloneCounter`.