# How to access dynamically created button?

Tags: javascript, html

```
btnUpdate = document.createElement("BUTTON");
var t = document.createTextNode("Update");
btnUpdate.id = 'update0';
btnUpdate.appendChild(t);
tabCell.appendChild(btnUpdate);
```

I have a simple line of code where I have created a button with my javascript. How do I access this button through the same javascript file? I want to add onClick feature to it.

```
document.getElementById("update0").onclick = edit_row(0);
```

I tried doing so by adding the above line of code, but now it won't display the table but straight away jumps to the edit_row() function.

Edit:

```
function showCustomer() {

  var obj, dbParam, xmlhttp, myObj, x, txt = "",tabCell;    
  var btnUpdate;
  obj = { "table":"Successful", "limit":20 };
  dbParam = JSON.stringify(obj); 
  xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
  if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
    myObj = JSON.parse(xmlhttp.responseText);
    console.log(myObj);
    var col = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < myObj.length; i++) {
        for (var key in myObj[i]) {
            if (col.indexOf(key) === -1) {
                col.push(key);
            }
        }
    }
    key="Update";
    col.push(key);
    console.log(col);
    // CREATE DYNAMIC TABLE.
    var table = document.createElement("table");

    // CREATE HTML TABLE HEADER ROW USING THE EXTRACTED HEADERS ABOVE.

    var tr = table.insertRow(-1);                   // TABLE ROW.

    for (var i = 0; i < col.length; i++) {
        var th = document.createElement("th");      // TABLE HEADER.
        th.innerHTML = col[i];
        tr.appendChild(th);
    }

    // ADD JSON DATA TO THE TABLE AS ROWS.
    for (var i = 0; i < myObj.length; i++) {

        tr = table.insertRow(-1);
        tabCell = null;
        for (var j = 0; j < col.length-1; j++) {
            tabCell = tr.insertCell(-1);
            tabCell.innerHTML = myObj[i][col[j]];
        }
        tabCell = tr.insertCell(-1);
        btnUpdate = document.createElement("BUTTON");
        var t = document.createTextNode("Update");
        btnUpdate.id = 'update'+i;
        btnUpdate.appendChild(t);
        tabCell.appendChild(btnUpdate);
    }
    tr = table.insertRow(-1);

        tabCell = null;
        for (var j = 0; j < col.length-1; j++) {
            tabCell = tr.insertCell(-1);
            tabCell.innerHTML = " ";
        }
        tabCell = tr.insertCell(-1);
        var btn = document.createElement("BUTTON");
        var t = document.createTextNode("Add Row");
        btn.appendChild(t);
        tabCell.appendChild(btn);

        document.getElementById("update0").addEventListener = function (){
            edit_row(0);
        };

    // FINALLY ADD THE NEWLY CREATED TABLE WITH JSON DATA TO A CONTAINER.
    var divContainer = document.getElementById("showData");
    divContainer.innerHTML = "";
    divContainer.appendChild(table);
    }
  };
  xmlhttp.open("POST", "http://localhost:8090/Vaccine", true);
  xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/JSON");
  xmlhttp.send("x=" + dbParam);  
}

function edit_row(no)
{
    alert("HELLO");
}
```

Comment: After you've created the button, you can add a listener to it, like so: `btnUpdate.addEventListener('click', function () {edit_row(0);});` The added listener will follow the button, no matter where ever you're going to append/insert the button later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With this line :

```
document.getElementById("update0").onclick = edit_row(0);
```

You are not "attaching" the click event to the edit_row function. You're setting the onclick property with the result of the edit_row(0) invokation.

Also, don't use the `onclick` property.

Use the [addEventListener](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) function instead.

```
document.getElementById("update0").addEventListener("click", function () {
    edit_row(0);
});
```

If you need a reason : by overwriting the `onclick` property, you could be disabling any other click event listener on your elements. By using `addEventListener()`, you can have several events listener on the same element/event couple.

And you can do this right after you created the button. You don't need to get it by its id later.

Your code would look like this :

```
btnUpdate = document.createElement("BUTTON");
var t = document.createTextNode("Update");
btnUpdate.id = 'update0';
btnUpdate.appendChild(t);
btnUpdate.addEventListener("click", function () {
    edit_row(0);
});
```

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'onclick' of null at XMLHttpRequest.xmlhttp.onreadystatechange                                                          Im getting this error for that line of code

Comment: You could solve this error by calling the addEventListener function right after you created your button. See my last edit.

Answer (score 1):

You have to do that in callback of on click event. If you inline, it executes directly when javascript reading your code.

```
document.getElementById("update0").onclick = function (){
    edit_row(0);
};
```

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'onclick' of null
    at XMLHttpRequest.xmlhttp.onreadystatechange                                           It is giving me this error for that line.

Comment: @KeshviSrivastava Could you please post full codes ? Looks like your element is null. Probably by accessing in a wrong way or your element does not exist.

Answer (score 0):

> How do I access this button through the same javascript file?

The same way you've been accessing it all along.

It is stored in the `btnUpdate` variable. Use that.

---

> but now it won't display the table but straight away jumps to the edit_row() function.

That is because you are **calling** `edit_row` and setting its *return value* as the click handler.

Since you want to pass arguments to it, the easiest thing to do is to create a new function.

```
function edit_row_first_argument_0 () {
    edit_row(0);
}

button.addEventListener("click", edit_row_first_argument_0);
```

(You can use an anonymous function expression, I use the verbose approach above for clarity).

Comment: As you can see above (I've uploaded the whole code now) I have multiple buttons all with the same var name. How do i access one specific button then?

Comment: @KeshviSrivastava — You know how you use `btnUpdate.id = 'update0';` to set the `id` property of the specific button you want to set? And you get the right button by doing it before you overwrite the `btnUpdate` variable with a new value? The same way.

Comment: i'm sorry but I still dont get it. Could you edit the code and share here?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
btnUpdate = document.createElement("BUTTON");
var t = document.createTextNode("Update");
btnUpdate.id = 'update0';
btnUpdate.appendChild(t);
tabCell.appendChild(btnUpdate);
btnUpdate.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
   // this linked to btnUpdate
   // Here make whatever you want
   // You can call edit_row now
   edit_row(0)
})
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that your button is not in the DOM yet, so you are not able to find it with `document`. You can use the variable `btnUpdate` if it is in the same file like `btnUpdate.onclick = function() {}`, or using `addEventListener`like `btnUpdate.addEventListener('click', function() {})`.

Also, it seems you are executing the `edit_row(0)` function. You need to put it inside a function like

```
btnUpdate.addEventListener('click', function() {
  edit_row(0);
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You call the function when you have () at the end so

```
document.getElementById("update0").onclick = edit_row(0);
```

will immediately call edit_row

Why not do this instead:

```
btnUpdate = document.createElement("BUTTON");
var t = document.createTextNode("Update");
btnUpdate.id = 'update0';
btnUpdate.onclick=function() {
   edit_row(this.id.replace("update","")); // or use a data-attribute
}
btnUpdate.appendChild(t);
tabCell.appendChild(btnUpdate);
```

or use event delegation:

[Native JS equivalent to jquery delegation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25248286/native-js-equivalent-to-jquery-delegation)