# Adding even listener to multiple elements with matches()

Tags: javascript

I was trying to combine querySelectorAll and matches() to add even listener like this:

**HTML**

```
<div id="bkLst" class="dropdown-menu">
    <button class="dropdown-item" type="button" data-b="Book 1">Book 1</button>
    <button class="dropdown-item" type="button" data-b="Book 2">Book 2</button>
    <button class="dropdown-item" type="button" data-b="Book 12">Book 12</button>
</div>
```

**JS**

```
document.addEventListener("click", function(e){
    if(e.target.querySelectorAll.matches("#bkLst button")){
         ...
    }
});
```

But to no avail. What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you can select the buttons with `const elButtons = document.querySelectorAll("#bkLst button")`,  and loop over the buttons and add event listener like following

```
elButtons.forEach(el => {
  el.addEventListener("click", () => {
    //do something
  }
})
```

Answer (score 2):

```
let list = document.getElementById('bkLst');

let elements = list.querySelectorAll('.dropdown-item');

for(let element of elements){

   element.addEventListener('click', function() {

       console.log('iyeah')

    });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are attempting to create delegated event handling, similar to Jquery, then you only need to do `e.target.matches` with your selector, `matches` is meant to be called on a single element, not a collection. Please see my code snippet and related documentation: [Element.matches](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/matches), there are other posts on Stack Overflow which relate to native javascript version(s) of Jquery's delegate event handling, here's one for example - [native-js-equivalent-to-jquery-delegation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25248286/native-js-equivalent-to-jquery-delegation)

```js
document.addEventListener("click", function(e){
    if(e.target.matches("#bkLst button")){
         console.log("I'm button:" + e.target.textContent);
    }
});
```

```html
<div id="bkLst" class="dropdown-menu">
    <button class="dropdown-item" type="button" data-b="Book 1">Book 1</button>
    <button class="dropdown-item" type="button" data-b="Book 2">Book 2</button>
    <button class="dropdown-item" type="button" data-b="Book 12">Book 12</button>
</div>
```